# How to get a user's email from an access token using the Facebook Python SDK

Tags: python, facebook, email, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to implement Facebook login for an application I am developing.

I am getting an access token like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '[Redacted]',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.6'
    });

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        window.location = "http://[my domain]/FBloginAuth?"+FB.getAuthResponse()["accessToken"]
    } else {
        window.location = encodeURI("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?scope=email&client_id=[redacted]&redirect_uri=http://[my domain]/FBloginAuth&response_type=token");
    }
});

  };

  (function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
  </script>

  <div id="status"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

My server then fishes the access token from the url like this (Python 2, because I have to support the Google OAuth SDK which doesn't seem to support Python 3.):

```
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token=environ["QUERY_STRING"]) # Apparently there is an extrea
profile = graph.get_object('me')
args = {'fields' : 'id,name,email', }
profile = graph.get_object('me', **args)
print(profile)
```

I know that this doesn't parse cases where there are variables in the url. That is not the point. For now I am hand-feeding the token. The code vomits:

```
{u'id': u'[redacted]', u'name': u'[redacted]'}
```

My question is why the email doesn't appear in the response as I set the scope when asking for the token. Also, what should I do to get the email?

Comment: Make sure that a) the user has actually granted the permission to your app (request `/me/permissions` to confirm, using the same access token), and b) that their e-mail address is verified with Facebook.

Comment: Ok, I tried that. The email is verified (at least I logged in with it). Trying to request the /me/permissions gives:

Comment: {
   "error": {
      "message": "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 2500,
      "fbtrace_id": "G5cUTqW1eBL"
   }
}

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken says that the token is valid and that it has been granted both `basic_profile` and `email`.

Comment: Then you did not use that same access token for the request to `/me/permissions`, by the looks of it.

Comment: It seems I formatted the `/me/permissions` -request wrong. Nice catch. Now this is what I get:

Comment: {
   "data": [
      {
         "permission": "email",
         "status": "granted"
      },
      {
         "permission": "public_profile",
         "status": "granted"
      }
   ]
}

Comment: It would appear to me that both permissions are granted. Am I right in supposing that the email is confirmed if I use it to log in?

Comment: If it is not confirmed yet, then it should show the option in your FB settings.

Comment: Ok. That seems to solve it. Wanna write answer so I can mark this as solved or was the question too stupid to stay here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that

a) the user has actually granted the permission to your app (request `/me/permissions` to confirm, using the same access token), and

b) that their e-mail address is verified with Facebook. (Apparently not automatically the case with the e-mail address used to register.)